# Firebase Cloud Function updating ref with incorrect values

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to add a new node to the database if the node doesn't exist. I don't want to return anything to the client, I just want to update the database with the new values. On the client I have a listener that observes the `credit_counts` property, once the update happens it receives it there and notifies all users that this particular user has a new credit.

In the code below I check to see `if (!snapshot.exists()` and if it's not there I add the node to the database using `admin.database().ref('/user_credits/{creditId}/{userId}').set({ dict });`. After pasting the url I check the db and the layout is:

[image]

I'm a Swift developer. In Swift I can just do:

```
Database.database().reference().child("/user_credits/\(creditId)/\(userId)").setValue(dict) and the tree will be correct.
```

`user_credits > {creditId} > {userId} > dict` are incorrect. It should be `user_credits > sample_123 > user_xyz > dict values`. Where am I going wrong at?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.updateViewsCtAtPostsRef = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    const currentTimeStamp = Date.now();
    const receivedTimeStamp = admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;

    const creditId = "sample_123";
    const userId = "userId_xyz";

    admin.database().ref('user_credits').child(creditId).child(userId).once('value', snapshot => {

        if (!snapshot.exists()) {

            var dict = {
                "joined_date": receivedTimeStamp,
                "timeStamp": receivedTimeStamp,
                "credits_count": 1
            };

            return admin.database().ref('/user_credits/{creditId}/{userId}').set({ dict });

        } else {

            const previousTimeStamp = snapshot.child("timeStamp").val();
            const creditsCount = snapshot.child("credits_count").val();

            if (previousTimeStamp + whatever) < currentTimeStamp {

                let updatedCount = creditsCount + 1

                return admin.database().ref('/user_credits/{creditId}/{userId}').update({ "timeStamp": receivedTimeStamp, "credits_count": updatedCount });

            } else {

               return true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If it was a syntax issue, then your code would generate an error - JavaScript does not run with syntax errors.  Please edit the question to show that error.  If there is no error, then something else is wrong.  In that case, add some logging and show what you've learned from that debugging.

Comment: Ohhhh ok, it must not be a syntax issue, I'll remove that from the question, I thought it was

Comment: I'm also noticing that your function never sends a response to the client, which is required for all http functions.  Please edit the question to state what this function is supposed to actually do when invoked.

Comment: ok give me a second, I'm new to cloud functions. I just started using them yesterday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the ref to:

```
return admin.database().ref('/user_credits/' + creditId + '/' + userId).set({ "joined_date": receivedTimeStamp, "timeStamp": receivedTimeStamp, "credits_count": 1 });
```

I also had to update the ref inside the else statement to follow the same format.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is fine, but the reference does not match the structure; that should rather be:

```
admin.database().ref('user_credits').child(creditId).child(userId).child('dict')
```

... else there won't be any `snapshot.child("timeStamp")` or `snapshot.child("credits_count")`.

Comment: I'm trying the code with your answer but the logs say that it keeps timing out. Once it goes through I'll let you know the results.

Comment: It keeps timing out, is the last child supposed to be have dict in single quotes? `.child('dict')`